# How to fix the height of an image in CSS even when the window is smaller than the width of the image

Tags: html, css, image

This is perhaps a bit of a strange issue that I have with creating the background for my website. I have created an SVG image of dimensions 1000x1000 that can be tiled seamlessly horizontally. I would like the background image to stay 1000px tall regardless of the size of the window. However, if the window is wider than 1000px I would like the image to repeat horizontally. So far for my CSS image, I have the following attributes:

```
Background: {
        backgroundImage: `url(${background})`,
        backgroundRepeat:'repeat-x',
        height: '1000px',
        width: '100%',
    }
```

This works for the most part. When the window is larger than 1000px wide the image repeats perfectly. However, when I then shrink the window down until it is less than 1000px tall, the image begins to shrink so that one full image is still displayed on the page. And therefore the image is no longer 1000px tall.

Another thing I have tried is:

```
Background: {
        backgroundImage: `url(${background})`,
        backgroundRepeat:'repeat-x',
        height: '1000px',
        width: '100%',
        backgroundPosition: 'center',
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        position: 'relative'
    }
```

In this situation, the image is always 1000px tall. However when even when I specify to `repeat-x`, the image itself grows to fill the width when the page is wider than 1000px. Rather than repeating the image.

What am I missing? Would love to hear any ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, my first suggestion would be to set a minimum width using a media query so that when the viewport goes below 1000px it snaps to 1000px and stays there.

First, you would add this to the top of your HTML in the header

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Then you would add this CSS

```
@media (max-height: 1000px) {  
    .Background {
        background-size: 100% 1000px;
    }
}
```

Then, when screens go lower than 1000px, it will force the background to

Comment: Yes, this was exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem :). If you mark my answer as "Accepted" I'd really appreciate it. It just gives me e-reputation so I can post on more topics. Thanks either way!